# Splitting data frame into lists holding one column constant

Tags: r

I have some time series data which looks like:

Data:

```
   date          FB  AMZN  GOOG  MSFT
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2016-01-04 102.   637.  742.  54.8
 2 2016-01-05 103.   634.  743.  55.0
 3 2016-01-06 103.   633.  744.  54.0
 4 2016-01-07  97.9  608.  726.  52.2
 5 2016-01-08  97.3  607.  714.  52.3
 6 2016-01-11  97.5  618.  716.  52.3
```

Code:

```
data <- tidyquant::tq_get(c("FB", "AMZN", "GOOG", "MSFT"),
                  get  = "stock.prices",
                  from = "2016-01-01",
                  to   = "2017-01-01") %>% 
  dplyr::select(symbol, date, close) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = symbol, values_from = close)
```

I want to hold one column fixed and store as a list combinations of the `zoo` objects.

I can manually save the results as `zoo` objects using:

```
time.points <- seq.Date(as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 252)
# For GOOG and MSFT
tsGOOG <- ts(data$GOOG)
tsMSFT <- ts(data$MSFT)
tsData1 <- zoo(cbind(tsGOOG, tsMSFT), time.points)

# For GOOG and AMZN
tsGOOG <- ts(data$GOOG)
tsAMZN <- ts(data$AMZN)
tsData2 <- zoo(cbind(tsGOOG, tsAMZN), time.points)

# For GOOG and FB
tsGOOG <- ts(data$GOOG)
tsFB <- ts(data$FB)
tsData3 <- zoo(cbind(tsGOOG, tsFB), time.points)
```

I would like to do the above but by mapping over the columns, holding the `GOOG` column fixed (i.e. the `GOOG` column will be constant in each of the lists, appearing in each list).

EDIT:

I have been trying using `pivot_longer` and then `group_split`. Once the groups are split into a list, I can maybe join the `GOOG` data frame with all other data frames in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** This gives a list of 2 column xts/zoo objects given a character vector `tickers` of ticker symbols.  get.close takes a ticker and returns an xts/zoo object of closes.  f combines the GOOG closes with the closes of the ticker given as its argument.  Then Map applies it over the non-GOOG tickers.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c("FB", "AMZN", "GOOG", "MSFT")

get.close <- function(sym) {
  Cl(getSymbols(sym, from = "2016-01-01", to = "2017-01-01", auto = FALSE))
}

GOOG.cl <- get.close("GOOG")
f <- function(sym) cbind(GOOG.cl, get.close(sym))
L <- Map(f, setdiff(tickers, "GOOG"))
```

**2)** To get that output from `data` (as defined in the question) use:

```
library(xts)
x <- as.xts(read.zoo(data))
L2 <- Map(function(sym) x[, c("GOOG", sym)], setdiff(tickers, "GOOG"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well for the finance data but my actual data is not finance (it has the exact same structure as the finance data here) so using the `get.close` function does not work with my data. The output you have is exactly what I want however.

Comment: Have added that.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! it works on my original data also.